# Facebook share: title is not displaying on share box

Tags: facebook

I am sharing my link to Facebook. When I click the share button, it goes to the Facebook share page. Everything is fine except the title is not displayed, although the title is there in the query string.

Below is my code. Please guide me in details that how to display title and description also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Humayoo Social Book Mark</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Smith hails 'unique' Wable legacy" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="John Smith claims beautiful football is the main legacy of Akhil Wable's decade at the club. " /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.onjd.com/design05/images/PH2/WableAFC205.jpg" />
<meta name="medium" content="blog" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function whenclick() {
        var uri = "http://192.168.1.10/test.aspx&t=abc";//here my domain name or ip
        window.location = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+uri;
    }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="whenclick();">Share</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be happening because of it can not be linted by Facebook properly that you try from localhost.

To see whats happening in Facebook-side, try Debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You can see open graph meta information gathered by Facebook and also errors that you have.

Comment: i am able to fixed.if any body need help.please ask with me.